# Issue with Paste Loop while negative

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple copy arrays and 3 different paste arrays. I want to copy the pallet type, SKU, and corresponding cases based on the cases being negative from a new workbook and paste it into the current workbook. Then I want to paste that information into the current workbook with the corresponding information. I think I have the code to where it is copying the information, but it is not pasting any of the information to the current workbook.

[image]

```
 Sub buildPlan()
'
' buildPlan Macro
'
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim colValsF, colValsE, colValsB As Collection
    Dim v, arr, c, d, e As Range
    Dim nwb As Workbook, wsAPP As Worksheet, wsDNDR As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook           'ThisWorkbook?
    Set wsAPP = wb.Worksheets("Arils Pack Plan ") 'trailing space?
    
    'Opening Recent ATS report
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    End With
    
    Set wsDNDR = nwb.Worksheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    
    Set colValsE = New Collection
    Set colValsF = New Collection
    Set colValsB = New Collection
    'Collect Pallet----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Set d = wsDNDR.Range("E5:E14,E15:E25").Cells
    
    For Each c In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14,T5:T14,Q15:Q25,T15:T25").Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v < 0 Then colValsE.Add d
    Next c
    
    arr = CollectionToArray(colValsE) 'transfer the collection values to an array
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        wsAPP.Range("E7").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 1) = arr 'place the array on the sheet
    End If
  'Collect SKU --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  Set e = wsDNDR.Range("B5:B14,B15:B25").Cells
  
  For Each c In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14,T5:T14,Q15:Q25,T15:T25").Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v < 0 Then colValsB.Add e
    Next c
    
    arr = CollectionToArray(colValsB) 'transfer the collection values to an array
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        wsAPP.Range("B7").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 1) = arr 'place the array on the sheet
    End If
    
    
    'collect all of the negative values----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    For Each c In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14,T5:T14,Q15:Q25,T15:T25").Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v < 0 Then colValsF.Add v
    Next c
    
    arr = CollectionToArray(colValsF) 'transfer the collection values to an array
    If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
        wsAPP.Range("F7").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 1) = arr 'place the array on the sheet
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not really following your workflow - can you add a screenshot of the data you're working with?  Or if you can share a workbook that would also work...

Comment: Might be useful to include the column and row headers in your screenshot, so we can relate the ranges in your code to the screenshot.

Comment: Okay so I need to copy the first column and second based on the criteria of the third and 4th column being negative. Then paste the first and second columns to a different workbook in separate columns. and the 3rd and 4th need to be in the same column. But, the ranges need to end on the horizontal black line. So essentially it will look in the 3rd column and if it is negative copy the information from the 3rd column and corresponding information from the 1st and 2nd. Then repeat the process with the 4th column once it's done with that it will need to move below the horizontal black line and

Comment: repeat the process it did above the horizonal black line.

Comment: Note: `Dim colValsF, colValsE, colValsB As Collection` only colValsB is a collection. The other two are variants.

Comment: Same with `Dim v, arr, c, d, e As Range`, only e is a Range. I'd suggest giving your variables meaningful names as it'd help you later when you have to maintain this, as well as help people now.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated it with the rows and columns

Answer (score 1):

Now I see what you're doing there is a much simpler approach: loop over the rows of the data and process each one in turn, instead of doing it column-by-column.

```vb
Sub buildPlan()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rwDest As Range, rw As Range, valQ, valT
    Dim nwb As Workbook, wsAPP As Worksheet, wsDNDR As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook           'ThisWorkbook?
    Set wsAPP = wb.Worksheets("Arils Pack Plan ") 'trailing space?
    
    'Opening Recent ATS report
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then Set nwb = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
    If nwb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no file selected...
    Set wsDNDR = nwb.Worksheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    
    Set rwDest = wsAPP.Rows(7) 'start row for results
    
    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("A5:T25").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valQ < 0 Or valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("B").Value = rw.Columns("B").Value 'SKU
            rwDest.Columns("E").Value = rw.Columns("E").Value 'pallet
            rwDest.Columns("F").Value = valQ & "," & valT  'list both values
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw    
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! I will give this a try!

Comment: Hello Tim. Could you help me with my most recent question?