# Paste loop is not pasting values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```
Sub buildPlan()
'
' buildPlan Macro
'
    
   Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rwDest As Range, rw As Range, valQ, valT
    Dim nwb As Workbook, wsAPP As Worksheet, wsDNDR As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook           'ThisWorkbook?
    Set wsAPP = wb.Worksheets("Arils Pack Plan ") 'trailing space?
    
    'Opening Recent ATS report
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
    Set nwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    End With
    
    
    Set wsDNDR = nwb.Worksheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    
    Set rwDest = wsAPP.Rows(7) 'start row for results
    
    '4oz Day 1 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        If valQ < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("B7").Value = rw.Columns("B7").Value 'SKU
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw
    
    
    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        If valQ < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("E7").Value = rw.Columns("E7").Value 'VALUE
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw

    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        If valQ < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("F7").Value = valQ 'Value
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw

    '4oz Day 2---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("T5:T14").Rows
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("B7").Value = rw.Columns("B7").Value 'SKU
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw
    
    
   For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("T5:T14").Rows
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("E7").Value = rw.Columns("E7").Value 'Pallet Type
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw


    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("T5:T14").Rows
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("F7").Value = valT 'Value
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw


    '8oz Day 1---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("Q15:Q26").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        If valQ < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("B7").Value = rw.Columns("B7").Value 'SKU
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw
    
    
   For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("Q15:Q26").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        If valQ < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("E7").Value = rw.Columns("E7").Value 'Pallet Type
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw


    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("Q15:Q26").Rows
        valQ = rw.Columns("Q").Value
        If valQ < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("F7").Value = valQ 'Value
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw

    '8oz Day 2---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("T15:T26").Rows
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("B7").Value = rw.Columns("B7").Value 'SKU
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw
    
    
   For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("T15:T26").Rows
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("E7").Value = rw.Columns("E7").Value 'Pallet Type
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw


    For Each rw In wsDNDR.Range("T15:T26").Rows
        valT = rw.Columns("T").Value
        If valT < 0 Then
            rwDest.Columns("F7").Value = valT 'Value
            Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1) 'Next row
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub
```

I am trying to paste the values from the Tracker to the Pack Plan if they are negative. I need to past the values from section 3 to column F in the pack plan. With its corresponding cells in section 1 and 2 from the tracker, then repeat that process if the values in section 4 are negative. Section 1 needs to be pasted in column B of the pack plan and section 2 needs to be pasted in column E of the pack plan. I need to finish the top sections (1-4) before moving onto the bottom sections (5-8). The process will be the same. I need to copy and paste the values with their corresponding cells in 5 and 6. Once the top section is pasted in the pack plan I need the bottom section to paste below the the top section on the pack plan.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes I added the code now

Comment: `.Columns("B7")` and `.Columns("E7")` look off. `Columns` does not use row numbers. So `.Columns("B")` or `.Columns("E")` or `.Columns(2)` or `.Columns(5)` is valid.

Comment: Always helps to link to your previous post. 
 If you get an answer but it doesn't do what you need then you should ideally follow up in that same post, rather than post a new question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75261506/478884

Comment: `wsDNDR.Range("Q5:Q14").Rows` is already limiting itself to Column Q, which means `rw.Columns("Q")` is moving over as if starting from Column A, but since it was already in column Q, it is adding those two offsets together, retrieving Column 33 (AG)

Comment: Okay. How would I go about setting multiple ranges and seeing if the value with in that range is negative copy a specific value and paste it in another cell in a different workbook. I believe the code above uses too many functions versus just have more base code.

Comment: Same issues with `Columns("T")`. If the range isn't starting from "A", using `.Columns("T")` is doubling down on the column offset, and you're getting the wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight modification of my answer in your previous post:

```vb
Sub buildPlan()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rwDest As Range, rw As Range, sRng, rngLoop As Range
    Dim nwb As Workbook, wsAPP As Worksheet, wsDNDR As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook           'ThisWorkbook?
    Set wsAPP = wb.Worksheets("Arils Pack Plan ") 'trailing space?
    
    'Opening Recent ATS report
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then Set nwb = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
    If nwb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no file selected...
    Set wsDNDR = nwb.Worksheets("DAILY NEED (DR)")
    
    Set rwDest = wsAPP.Rows(7) 'start row for results
    
    For Each sRng In Array("A5:T14", "A15:T25") 'row ranges to loop over
        Set rngLoop = wsDNDR.Range(sRng)        'rows to loop over
        For Each rw In rngLoop.Rows
            CheckRow rw, rwDest, "Q" 'check col Q
        Next rw
        For Each rw In rngLoop.Rows
            CheckRow rw, rwDest, "T" 'check Col T
        Next rw
    Next sRng
End Sub

'If the value in column `onHandColLett` of `rwSrc` is negative
'   then transfer some values to `rwDest`
Sub CheckRow(rwSrc As Range, rwDest As Range, onHandColLett)
    Dim v
    v = rwSrc.Columns(onHandColLett).Value
    If v < 0 Then
        rwDest.Columns("B").Value = rwSrc.Columns("B").Value 'SKU
        rwDest.Columns("E").Value = rwSrc.Columns("E").Value 'pallet
        rwDest.Columns("F").Value = v                        'on hand value
        Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1)                        'Next row
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if I am reading this code correctly, but I see that it will go through column q while copying column B completely. However, I need it to stop at row 14 then move to column t and repeat the process it was doing for column q. And repeat that process for rows 15:26.

Comment: The reason being is I need it to paste the columns in order in the pack plan. I need rows 5:14 to be first with information from all the columns Q(Q being first) and T being the criteria, while also pasting the values in those columns. Then I need it to repeat that process for rows 15:26 using those same columns.

Comment: OK - made some changes above - it will loop over A5:T14 then A15:T25, and check col Q and then col T for each of those ranges.

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you! Also, is there a way to add a space when copying to the new workbook between the pasting of the top section and bottom section?

Comment: You can call `Set rwDest = rwDest.offset(1)` to move the output row down

Comment: Where would I do this? Also, I just need it to move down 1 row only once.

Comment: Just before `Next sRng`